# What other blends are as *historical* as Mocha Java?

Tags: history

Mocha Java is a blend of Mocha coffee from Yemen (or sometimes Mocca coffee from Ethiopia) with [Java coffee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_coffee) from the island of [Java in Indonesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specialty_Coffee_Association_of_Indonesia) originally developed by the Dutch East India company, presumably as a side venture to fund their pursuit of pirate gold.

But be that as it may, what other coffee blends have a history? Are there other blends that show up in many different brands' offerings, perhaps under slightly different names? What's the corporate piracy looking like nowadays and 'ereabouts?

Comment: I'm putting this question on hold as it's asking for a long list of things, with a fairly loose criteria for inclusion. There's also a couple of different questions being asked. I'd suggest narrowing down your question and making it more specific.

Comment: @fredley I understand your concerns. Thanks for the note. I'm considering adding some objective criteria like "historicity" (first available >100 years ago), "ubiquity" (is/was offered by >=2 companies), "longevity" (has been continuously/cumulatively available for >50 years (two generations)). But, even then it *is* still a poll. Would these constraints be sufficient?

Comment: [Meta-question about this question and the broader issue of Polls.](http://meta.coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1158/do-we-want-some-kinds-of-poll-type-list-or-fishing-questions)